# Переход на новую строку в файле

Tags: файлы, c++

Привет всем!

Как правильно осуществить переход на новую строку в файле? Т.е. как правильно вставить '\n' так, чтобы в файле не пропадали следующие два символа? Чтение должно осуществляться по символу.

Искала ответ на данный вопрос, пока ничего толкогого не нашла. Извиняюсь, если нубский вопрос. Новичок. Заранее благодарю!

**Обновление**

Вот код: http://paste.ee/p/OqhB5

Не дописала условия. По ним нельзя проводить такие манипуляции.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream f("london.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    if (f.is_open()){
        char c;
        int symb_string = 0; 
        int count_letter = 0; 
        int position = 0; 
        f.get(c);
        while (f){
            f.get(c);
            position++;
            symb_string++;

            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ||
                c == ' ' || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '!' || c == '?' || c == '(' || c == ')'){
                count_letter++; 
                position++;
                symb_string++;
            }
            if (symb_string >= 20){
                if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
                    f.seekp(position - count_letter + 1);
                    f.put('\n');

                    count_letter = 0; 
                    symb_string = 0; 
                }
                else if (c == ' ' || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '!' || c == '?' || c == '(' || c == ')'){
                    f.seekp(position + 1);
                    f.put('\n');

                    count_letter = 0; 
                    symb_string = 0; 
                }
            }
            else continue;
        }
        printf("Done!");
        f.close();
    }
    else printf("File could not be open");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код в студию!

Comment: До позиции вставки скопируйте текст в новый файл, вставьте в этот новый файл символ перевода строки, скопируйте остаток текста в новый файл. Удалите старый и переименуйте новый файл.

Comment: вот код: http://paste.ee/p/OqhB5

не дописала условия. по ним нельзя проводить такие манипуляции.